# Is it possible to add our .class in JRE/JDK and using it in other java programs using that JRE/JDK?

Tags: java, jar

I will create a java class file. I will put the .class file in a jar. i will put the jar in jre/lib folder. Will i be able to call/execute that class in my other programs.

Comment: Why not put a jar instead of a class file ? (The jar may contains only one class, no problem here)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the correct place for that would be `jre/lib/ext` directory, as explained in [official doc for "installed extensions"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html)

Comment: Do I need to add anything in any other file for that jar to get recognized. e.g. meta-index file

Comment: Not for running your program, no. But when you develop that program, you must use a JDK that has this extension (under `/path/to/jdk/jre/lib/ext`), or the compiler and your IDE will not "recognize" that unknown class you're trying to use.